# Open Thickbox on button Click

Tags: .net, events, buttonclick

I am trying to open a thick box `onClientclick` event of asp:Button, the problem is the thick box is coming up for a sec, and then suddenly disappears (disappears as page load completed to be very specific), How it can be implemented?

Here is my code:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnAddNew" runat="server" Text="Add New" CssClass="button" ToolTip="Add New"
 OnClientClick="javascript:tb_show('','~/Forms/MyPage.aspx?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=500&width=1000')" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several way, I got the solution for it.
1. Create an input button.

```
<input type="button" runat="server" title="Add" id="btnAdd" value="Add" />
```

2. Create a javascript function that will be called to open a thick box.

> ```
> function OpenThickBox(urltb) 
> {
>       tb_show('Confirmation', urltb, 'null');
> }
> ```

3.Now, in your code behind on page load, add the attribute to your button for its onclick event

> ```
> string url = ResolveClientUrl("~/Forms/MyPage.aspx?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=500&width=1000");
> btnAdd.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return OpenThickBox('" + url + "');");
> ```

Thanks.